# In Visual Studio, when searching entire solution, coworker get's results much faster than I do

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When I search our large solution for a word, it takes about a minute or two for the entire solution to be searched.  I thought this was normal.  Then, at a co-worker's desk, he searched his copy of the solution and it took 10 seconds at most.

I asked him what he did and he said he did nothing special.

Any ideas of how I can speed up my search results?

Comment: Are you on the same hardware ? An SSD disk can significantly speed things up (build and search specifically).

Comment: I noticed in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 the speed of some of the Team Foundation actions were increased, maybe the search was to?

Answer (score 1):

He probably performed a search before you asked him to. Start brand new visual studio instances (one on each box) and try again, you probably will get the same time; if not, he has a better machine than you, or a machine that has more disk space or is less fragmented.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use the same search settings? Case sensitive, regex/wildcards, ... Could be a huge performance difference.

Answer (score 1):

It can depend on a lot of stuff

- hardware differences
- softwares installed
- antivirus options
- user policies/permissions

The pretty good start point, in my opinion, could be this guide [Speedup Visual Studio Guide](http://lennybacon.com/2010/10/18/UltimateGuideToSpeedUpVisualStudio.aspx)